# Scope and usage of 'not' in a sentence

Tags: usage, conjunctions, negation

I intend to say in the following statement that good people should pledge not to be silent and the righteous should win over the non-deserving. I'm not sure if the 'not' is being extended to the second part of the sentence.

> Let the good people pledge to **not** be silent and let the non-deserving win over the righteous.

1. If the sentence is not right, then how to correct this? (Adding an extra 'not' after and'?)
2. Can you describe the scenarios, if there's any, when the influence of 'not' extends across to the second sub-clause?

Comment: Too many negatives in one sentence can be confusing. An alternative could be "Let the good people pledge to speak out and let the righteous win over the non-deserving."

Comment: Or to use **neither/nor**: **....neither to be silent, nor to let the non-deserving...**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!
Can you comment what *actually* my sentence means in its current form?

Comment: It means - the good people should speak up and not be silent, and let the non-deserving people win their rights over the more deserving ones.

Comment: On first read, I see two parallel phrases here, both starting with *let*:

1. Let the good people pledge to not be silent...
and
2. [L]et the non-deserving win over the righteous.

This isn't the meaning you intend, I would assume, even if I understand the meaning you intend.